# English language support for Assassin's Creed origins xbox one arabic version

Tags: xbox-one, assassins-creed-origins

I have got assassin's creed origins for xbox one in arabic gulf version. Does it have english language support by default? Can I change the language settings to english?

Comment: What do you mean with "Arabic Gulf Version". There is only one version of the game. Did you download it from that store?

Comment: @Eric It says on the cover that it's arabic gulf version. My platform is ps4 and this one's for xbox one. What I need is to resell it to someone. One guy said it only supports arabic language ie, the texts in the game will be in arabic and not in english. I have no other way to confirm this.

Comment: Is it the retail version or the digital version?

Comment: @eric Retail version.

Comment: Try setting your console to English and start the game. If it plays in English, there you go!